# How to print maximum repeated word in a string with space or without space using php?

Tags: php

e.g.
  "helloworld hello world hello"

In above string "hello" is repeated 3 times in a string that is the maximum occurred word in the string.

So, output should be "hello"

Can you help me with this? I need the solution using PHP.

Comment: You need to make an attempt.  This looks like an interview or homework question.

Comment: Tried http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php?

Comment: What Nigel Ren said. Use a combination of http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php and count the occurences in the resulting array.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$word = 'helloworld hello world hello';
$all = str_word_count($word,1);
$count = [];

foreach ($all as $wrd)
        $count[$wrd] = substr_count ($word, $wrd);

$max = max($count);

foreach($count as $key => $val)
    if ($val == $max)
        echo $key;
```